# Static class cannot be resolved a type

Tags: android, static, android-asynctask, android-listfragment

I have a static class and I want to set a ListAdapter through the AsyncTask onPostExecute
but it gives the error : nestedObject cannot be resolved to a type

static class(nested class) :

```
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends ListFragment
    {
    public PostData[] listData;
    public PostItemAdapter adapter;
    //DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        this.generateDummyData();
        adapter = new PostItemAdapter(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        //task.execute();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_news, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void generateDummyData()
    {
        PostData data = null;
        listData = new PostData[10];
        // sets a default value to Date,Title and URL
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            data = new PostData();
            data.postDate = "May 20, 2013";
            data.postTitle = "Post " + (i + 1) + " Title: This is the Post Title from RSS Feed";
            data.postThumbUrl = null;
            listData[i] = data;
        }
    }
}
```

AsyncTask :

```
    public static class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<List<String>, Void, List<String>>
{
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(List<String>... urls)
    {
        FeedParser parser = FeedParserFactory.getParser();
        messages = parser.parse();
        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
        for (Message msg : messages)
        {
            titles.add(msg.getTitle());
        }
        return titles;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result)
    {
        MainActivity.DummySectionFragment nestedObject =  new MainActivity.DummySectionFragment();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (nestedObject.this,R.layout.fragment_section_nieuws, result);
        nestedObject.this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582824/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-trying-to-parse-in-a-asynctask) in a ListFragment instead of a ListActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `setListAdapter()` call, place `nestedObject.this` with just `nestedObject`.

The first form attempts to qualify the `this` pointer with a class name but `nestedObject` is an object reference, not a class name. You refer to *other* objects with the object reference and not with `this`.

For the `ArrayAdapter` constructor, pass in a valid `Context`. Since the class is a `static` inner class, it doesn't have access to the containing class. You'll need to pass in a `Context` such as your activity reference as an argument to the `DownloadWebPageTask`. For example:

```
public static class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<List<String>, Void, List<String>> {
    private Context mContext;

    DownloadWebPageTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    // now use mContext where a context is needed
```

(Note that holding onto an `Activity` reference like this can lead to significant memory leaks. But let's fix your build problems first. There are also many other problems in your code - interactively fixing them all is beyond the scope what SO questions are for.)

Comment: When I remove this I get two new errors saying : The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.DummySectionFragment,int,List<String>) is undefined

Comment: The DownloadWebPageTask is inside the MainActivity so I did this : `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this,R.layout.fragment_section_nieuws, result);` and now it throws : No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope

Comment: When I do this and add `mContext` where `MainActivity.this` is on the comment above I can no longer execute my task in the ListFragment

Comment: As you can see I update my DummySectionFragment class and it now throws : The constructor MainActivity.DownloadWebPageTask() is undefined on line `DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();`

Comment: Since we added an explicit constructor with `Context` arg, you need to pass e.g. `MainActivity.this` as an arg there: `new DownloadWebPageTask(MainActivity.this)`